# Make a request from my localhost client without cors error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, cors

I need to make a request from my localhosted nodejs/express js client to a 3rd party API that I hosted on the cloud. However each time I am trying I get a cors error. Curiously It works when I do the same request from postman but not from localhost with my nodejs app.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: file,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
        })
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: *I get a cors error.* Edit your question and add the CORS error message in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proxy to avoid CORS errors.get reference of this https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301 it might help you out